# Deleting a Task or List Item leads to "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

every time i try to delete either a list item or a task i get this error. it is nothing more than annoying, as i notice the deletion actually occurs, but i really want to turn it OFF. any way??

this is sharepoint 2010.

[image]

Comment: do you have an event receiver that might be handling the item?

Comment: could you explain? i haven't set anything up out of the ordinary...

Comment: nevermind then, you would know ;) is it occurring on other lists?

Comment: It appears based on the screenshot that there may be a workflow in place. If you delete an item, you are still modifying it and if there is a workflow setup this could be the problem. Just a thought!

Comment: any way i could work around this? you are correct there is a workflow on these lists.